# Is it possible to make a discord bot write in a word document? (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

So I'm trying to make a queue of people in discord and I got the bot to message me with the name of the person who joined the queue, but I don't know where to go from here. I'd like to make a list of the people who joined the queue, possibly in word. Does anyone know how I could do this?

I only started coding yesterday so I don't really know all the ins and outs. This is the code I currently have:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)|| message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }
    if(command === 'clear'){
        client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args);
    }
    if(command === 'embed'){
        client.commands.get('embed').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }
    if(message.content === `${prefix}joinqueue`){
        message.author.send('You have joined the queue!');
        console.log(`${message.author.username} joined the queue.`);
         client.users.fetch('518160902835666946').then(user => {
            user.send(`${message.author.username} joined the queue!`)
        })
    }
});
```

There are a few other commands, but the one I use for this is the last one. If you use the command it sends you a private message saying who joined and a private message to me saying that  joined the queue. I'd like the code to also add this persons name to a document so that I can see the order of the queue. I really don't care too much about the format, as long as I can see the order.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be hard for others to give you an answer that is not opinion-based. Could you edit your question to include your current code? Some additional details as to what is a preferred format of the document, and whether you want it to be append only or updated in real time. Also, where do you run your bot, does it have access to the file system or would it require an external API?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you would like to have a live-updated list. That means: If your Bot adds someone to queue you will see it immediately without having to reload.

Doing this with Word is misappropriate and very very difficult because word blocks the file from writing when you open it.

A few suggestions how you can archieve this:

**1. Firebase Realtime Database and companion App**

To get Started with the Realtime Datatbase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start.
As companion App I would suggest Electron because you stay in the same programming language: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start.
In this companion App you can show a live updated List.

In my opinion that is the best solution because here you are device undepended: You can recieve your queue on your mobile phone if you want to.

**2. IPC and Electron**

If you want to stay offline you can use a IPC (Internprocess Communication) connection to update an Electron app from your Discord Bot. This libary could be helpful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc

Thats the best solution if you want to stay offline and be independent of your internet connection.

**3. Simple-File and Notepad++**

Here you would save the queue proper formatted into a file and open it with notepad++ (download here: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/). Note to enable update silenty. Scroll to the last line after update can prevent the coursor from jumping around.

[image]

This is not a long-term solution because your disks speed may impact you and your disks service time will shrink extraordinary. (I have done that once and i have broken my ssd after a month) However if you want to start quickly this is a very error-resistant way of doing it.

I hope I have helped you,
if that wasn't the thing you wanted try to edit your question.

Happy coding,
BierDav